# this is a code for drawing using tkinter but using laser method in my class gives unexpected results

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, drawing, tkinter-canvas

I have written a code that has a class whose methods are called button command. The Problem comes when I use the laser method & I try to zoom in & out but after that if I again call the pen method using button command the cursor is somewhere & line drawn is somewhere else. Plzz help me solve this..

class drawline:

```
def __init__(self, win):

    self.win = win


    self.canvas = Canvas(self.win, width=1400, height=780, bg="White")
    self.scv = Scrollbar(self.win, orient="vertical")
    self.scv.place(x=1380, y=5, height=780)
    self.sch = Scrollbar(self.win, orient="horizontal")
    self.sch.place(x=0, y=775, width=1400)
    self.scv.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
    self.sch.config(command=self.canvas.xview)

    self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.scv.set,xscrollcommand=self.sch.set)
    self.canvas.create_window(0,0)

    self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('ALL'))

    self.rulep = PhotoImage(file="ruler.png", master=self.win)
    self.rulel = Label(self.win, image=self.rulep)
    self.bx = Button(self.win, text="X", font=('Algerian', 10), bg="White", fg="Red",
                     command=self.rulerforget)
    self.bx.bind('<Enter>', self.ruleun)
    self.bx.bind('<Leave>', self.btfor)
    self.active = None
    self.lastx, self.lasty = self.canvas.canvasx(0), self.canvas.canvasy(0)
    self.canvas.place(x=0, y=0)

def laser(self):
    self.canvas.configure(cursor="hand2")
    self.active = laser_b

    # self.canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.zoomer)
    self.canvas.bind("<Enter>", self.cancel_normal_scroll)
    self.canvas.bind("<Leave>", self.cancel_normal_scroll)

def zoomer(self, e):
    if self.active == laser_b:
        print(e.delta, e.x)

        if e.delta == 120:
            self.canvas.scale("all", e.x, e.y, 1.1, 1.1)
        elif e.delta == -120:
            self.canvas.scale("all", e.x, e.y, 0.9, 0.9)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))
        self.lastx = self.canvas.canvasx(0)
        self.lasty = self.canvas.canvasy(0)



def cancel_normal_scroll(self, event):
    return "break"

def pen(self):
    self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.xy)
    self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.addLine)
    self.canvas.configure(cursor="pencil")
    self.active = pen_b

def xy(self, event):
    if self.active == pen_b:
        self.lastx, self.lasty = event.x, event.y
        print(self.lastx,self.lasty)

def addLine(self, event):
    if self.active == pen_b:
        self.canvas.create_line((self.lastx, self.lasty, event.x, event.y))
        self.lastx, self.lasty = event.x, event.y

def erase(self):
    self.active = erase_b
    self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.xy)
    self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.use_eraser)
    self.canvas.configure(cursor="circle")

def use_eraser(self, event):
    if self.active == erase_b:
        self.canvas.create_oval((self.lastx, self.lasty, event.x, event.y), fill="White", outline="White", width=25)
        self.lastx, self.lasty = event.x, event.y
        self.canvas.after(1000, lambda: self.canvas.create_oval((self.lastx, self.lasty, event.x, event.y),
                                                                fill="White", outline="White", width=50))
        self.canvas.after(3000, lambda: self.canvas.create_oval((self.lastx, self.lasty, event.x, event.y),
                                                                fill="White", outline="White", width=100))

def note(self):
    self.active = note_b
    if self.active == note_b:
        self.entry = Text(self.win, bd=0, font=("Purisa", 15), fg="Black", bg="Yellow")
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.text)

def text(self, event):
    if self.active == note_b:
        self.textx = event.x
        self.texty = event.y
        self.entry.place(x=event.x, y=event.y, width=300, height=175)
        self.entry.focus_force()
        self.entry.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.canvastext)

def canvastext(self, event):
    if self.active == note_b:
        k = self.entry.get(1.0, 'end')
        self.mytext = self.canvas.create_text(self.textx, self.texty, text=k, font=('Algerian', 20))
        self.entry.place_forget()
        self.entry.delete(1.0, 'end')

def myruler(self):
    self.active = ruler_b
    self.rulel.place(x=200, y=200)
    self.rulel.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.on_move)
    self.rulel.bind('<Enter>', self.rulerplace)
    self.rulel.bind('<Leave>', self.btfor)

def rulerplace(self, event):
    if self.active == ruler_b:
        self.bx.place(in_=self.rulel, relx=0.98, rely=0.15)

def ruleun(self, event):
    if self.active == ruler_b:
        self.rulel.unbind('<Leave>')

def btfor(self, event):
    if self.active == ruler_b:
        self.bx.place_forget()

def rulerforget(self):
    if self.active == ruler_b:
        self.rulel.place_forget()
def rectangle(self):
    self.active = shape_b
    self.canvas.configure(cursor="crosshair")
    self.rect = None
    self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_button_press)
    self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_move_press)
    self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_button_release)


def on_move(self, event):
    if self.active == shape_b:
        component = event.widget
        locx, locy = component.winfo_x(), component.winfo_y()
        w, h = self.win.winfo_width(), self.win.winfo_height()
        mx, my = component.winfo_width(), component.winfo_height()
        xpos = (locx + event.x) - (15)
        ypos = (locy + event.y) - int(my / 2)
        if xpos >= 0 and ypos >= 0 and w - abs(xpos) >= 0 and h - abs(ypos) >= 0 and xpos <= w - 5 and ypos <= h - 5:
            component.place(x=xpos, y=ypos)


def on_button_press(self, event):
    if self.active == shape_b:
        # save mouse drag start position
        self.start_x = event.x
        self.start_y = event.y
        self.rect = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.lastx, self.lasty, 1, 1, fill="White", outline="Black")

def on_move_press(self, event):
    if self.active == shape_b:
        curX, curY = (event.x, event.y)

        # expand rectangle as you drag the mouse
        self.canvas.coords(self.rect, self.start_x, self.start_y, curX, curY)

def on_button_release(self, event):
    if self.active == shape_b:
        pass
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem but maybe you should recalculate positions for all elements when you zoom in & out. OR maybe you should use some variable `scale`, `offset` which are used to draw and which are changed when you zoom in & out.

Comment: I have used 2 variables lastx,lasty ....

Comment: I can't run it so I can't see problem. Better create minimal working code with this problem.